# Reuse https connection with libcurl (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, curl, https

I have a server A and multiple servers that are behind in a local network with the server A (Server A has connection outside)

Server A has a webpage that does multiple ajax request to a script like this

```
  //Get myserverB_IP from database
  ...
  $url = "https://myserverB_IP/someurl.php"  
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURL_VERSION_SSL,TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, false);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/sess.txt');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/sess.txt');
  curl_exec($ch);
  ...
```

With http, everything worked fine, but when adding https there is a big delay because every single ajax call requests a new key exchange to the serverB

There is any way to reuse the connection to avoid the key exchange in every request ?

Comment: I think that disabling the verification of the certificates could lead to potential MITM attacks (SSL/TLS is used to protect against those attacks).

Comment: I know, but I didn't set my ca yet (I don't expect to get any problem with that when I implement it, this script is just for testing purposes to try to speed up the process since the main problem I got now is that every request does the handshaking and generate new keys, which adds a 2-3 sec delay every ajax request

Comment: Look at this tutorial. I hope that it will help - http://tokenposts.blogspot.com/2013/02/php-curl-optimise-speed-reusing-ssl.html

Comment: Doesn't work for my setup, already saw that link :(, I can't reuse the handler since there are different ajax calls, and i think different instances of a script can't share handlers (At least what i tried using $_SESSION didn't worked out, i don't know if there's another way to share handlers ).

Comment: Just issue multiple requests with using single $ch. Should work like you want it - one https connection setup, and multiple requests.

Comment: This isn't supported with HTTP, SPDY will reuse the SSL connection, or you could do a websocket thing. But as long as you're issuing seperate requests, I think you're hosed.

Comment: Hey Micah, i ended up using a websocket saving the connections since i found a better solution